# ProgressDialog error...Leaked Window

Tags: java, android

I have a progress dialog, and I need when it finish counting to start an activity. But I get an error. So, here is my progress dialog method:

```
private void myProgress(){
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressBar.setCancelable(true);
        progressBar.setMessage("Hacking the profile ...");
        progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.show();
        progressBarStatus = 0;
        fileSize = 0;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                while (progressBarStatus < 100) {

                  // process some tasks
                  progressBarStatus = doSomeTasks();


                  try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                  // Update the progress bar
                  progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                      progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                    }
                  });
                }

                // progress 100%
                if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {

                    // sleep 2 seconds, so that you can see the 100%
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Start Result activity
                    Intent localIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
                    localIntent.putExtra("email", emailText.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(localIntent);
                }
              }
               }).start();

               }
```

And doSomeTasks method:

```
public int doSomeTasks() {

        while (fileSize <= 1000000) {

            fileSize++;

            if (fileSize == 100000) {
                return 10;
            } else if (fileSize == 200000) {
                return 20;
            } else if (fileSize == 300000) {
                return 30;
            }
            else if (fileSize == 400000) {
                return 40;
            }
            else if (fileSize == 500000) {
                return 50;
            }
            else if (fileSize == 600000) {
                return 60;
            }
            else if (fileSize == 700000) {
                return 70;
            }
            else if (fileSize == 800000) {
                return 80;
            }
            else if (fileSize == 900000) {
                return 90;
            }

        }

        return 100;

    }
```

I get error on this line:

```
 localIntent.putExtra("email", emailText.getText().toString());
```

LogCat:

```
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497): Activity com.myapps.someapp.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@a6aa84f0 that was originally added here
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.myapps.someapp.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@a6aa84f0 that was originally added here
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at com.myapps.someapp.MainActivity.hackAccount(MainActivity.java:67)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at com.myapps.someapp.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:60)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at com.myapps.someapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:54)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-23 14:47:20.946: E/WindowManager(1497):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: dismiss progress dialog in onDestroy(). i know its not related to the error. but try it

Comment: Did you tried with progressBar = new ProgressDialog(ClassName.this);

Comment: probably getting error because you are trying to access EditText from non UI Thread or you forget to initialize Edittext instance

Comment: @Hardy yes, still get the error.

Comment: "or you forget to initialize Edittext instance"...You got it. But I did not forgt as much I made a mistake, misspelled. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An AsyncTask seems to be more appropriate for you need:

```
fileSize = 0;
private class HackingTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    // Before running code in separate thread
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(this);
         progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
         progressDialog.setMessage("Hacking the profile ...");
         progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
         progressDialog.setProgress(0);
         progressDialog.setMax(100);
         progressDialog.show();
    }

    // The code to be executed in a background thread.
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {

              while (progressDialog.getProgress() < 100) {
                  publishProgress(doSomeTasks());

                  try {
                     Thread.sleep(500);
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                   }
              }
    }

    // Update the progress
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // set the current progress of the progress dialog
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    // after executing the code in the thread
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void... arg) {
        // close the progress dialog
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

And to run it:

```
new HackingTask().execute();
```

Comment: This error android.view.WindowLeaked:  comes up when you are trying to show the progressbar even when the activity is not active. dismiss the proressbar.progressbar.dismiis() inside a null!= progressbar check before going to other activity.

Comment: @tsp no it is not, just wanted to show the usage of AsyncTask doing the same work as marjanbaz did in his code. Assuming he just want to see the progressbar slowly progress.

Comment: @tsp whoops now I see what you mean, forgot the while loop

Answer (score 0):

The error says, that you're trying to open the Dialog for an Activity that is already closed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Is your Activity running while the ProgressBar is shown?